# Reducing PhoneGap load time

Tags: cordova

PhoneGap shows a splash screen while the app loads.

I've tested the sample application from [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start). Loading the app on Nexus 7, Samsung Note 8, Samsung S3 it takes on average 5+ seconds to start for the first time.

If there a way to reduce this delay?

Compared to other HTML5 apps that I've tried on the same device. They seem to load much quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be aware that the app, when loading, is instantiating itself and then an entire web browser.  This does take a few seconds.  In my testing, on for example an S3 this does take 3 seconds or so, however when started again as it's now in the background paused, it doesn't take nearly as long - under a second.

This isn't abnormal for other apps, based on PhoneGap or otherwise.  Other HTML5 'apps' aren't necessarily 'native' and might well load quicker - are they just shortcuts to a website?

Comment: I don't think their shortcuts. Is there a way to inspect an app to see if it was build using PhoneGap?